# Wrong argument count, format string resource_name requires 3 but format call supplies 2 Android string

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

I have a resource which is in an html format since i want to display it like that

```
<string name="calculator_bottom_sheet_body" translatable="false">
        <![CDATA[<b>Basic requirements</b><br /><br />
You must be between 18 - 70 in order to proceed:
        <ul>
            <li> requirement 1</li>
            <li> requirement 2</li>
            <li> requirement 3 and</li>
            <li> requirement 4</li>
        </ul> <br /><br />

<b>Money requirement:</b><br /><br />
From €500 to €15.000<br /><br />

<b>Duration:</b><br /><br />
From 6 to 84 months<br /><br />
        If you like to continue press the button below.]]>
    </string>
```

and from the Fragment i retrieve the string like that

```
val body = resources.getString(R.string.calculator_bottom_sheet_body)
```

That works just fine.
However i want the €500, €15.000 values to variables like €%s, €%s. So after i convert the line

```
From €%s to €%s<br /><br />
```

i need to call the resource from the fragment like

```
val body = resources.getString(R.string.calculator_bottom_sheet_body, minAmount, maxAmount)
```

And thats where i get this error

```
Wrong argument count, format string calculator_bottom_sheet_body requires 1 but format call supplies 2
```

Does anybody know whats the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your string from

```
From €%s to €%s<br /><br />
```

to

```
From €%1$s to €%2$s<br /><br />
```

and use it like

```
val body = String.format(context.getResources().getString(R.string.calculator_bottom_sheet_body), minAmount, maxAmount)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation,

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings

you have to define the arguments positions like this:

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>


var text = getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount)
```